# Xamarin Android app not reading files in Android 13 (API 33)

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm facing an issue with my Xamarin Android app, specifically when running it on Android 13 (API 33). The app works perfectly fine on lower Android versions (from 5 to 10), but on Android 13, it's unable to read files from both internal and external storage access denied. However, it can successfully write files to these locations.

Here's how I'm currently retrieving file paths in my app:

```
public static string Pass()
{
    return Path.Combine((string)System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "pass.licns");
}

public static string Course()
{
    return Path.Combine((string)System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "course.licns");
}
```

And here's the relevant portion of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="19" android:versionName="3.0" package="com.player" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <application android:label="Player" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="false"></application>
</manifest>
```

I've tried various solutions found on Stack Overflow, but none of them seem to work for Android 13. It's important to note that my app can write files successfully, but reading files is the issue.

Any guidance on how to make my app work on Android 13 regarding file reading would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Yes on an Android 13 device your app can create files in all public directories on external storage without any permission.

Comment: But it cannot read files of other apps. Well.. not in the classic way.

Comment: You schould try Android 11 and 12 devices too.

Comment: `on Android 13, it's unable to read files from both internal and external storage ` Hmmm . I wonder what exactly you consider to be internal storage. Full path please.

Comment: @blackapps i tried different location of internal storage like document folder and app directory but still same error access denied all library are up to date of Xamarain. internal storage means Primary Storage of smartphone and external sdcard hope you understand.

Comment: Well i told you all in my first comments. Did you read them?

Comment: so whats the solution its not reading file after writing?

Comment: I dont see code where you create a file and then try to read it.